# HUE beeswax can not load databases when lots people do queries

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Nsui.png)Our group members used beeswax to do the hive queries.
When few people do the query,everything is okay. 
But when lots people do the query at the same time or in a short time,something strange happened. The database list keep loading and the whole browser will be no response.At this time, the cores of hive servers and metastore servers were always more than one core.
So I had to wait for a long time or restart the whole hive server and everything going okay again.
I had checked the log of hue and hive server,but found nothing useful.(so sad of it)
I had worked for this question for a every log time but could not get the solution of this problem.
Because of the limit of network,I can not paste the screenshots and any logs  here.
Are there anyone can help me.
I search this picture from internet.I made a mark on it.When the problem happened,there is a loading icon on the it and it was impossible to change database.

Comment: by the way,the  CDH version is 5.4.6,HUE version is 3.7.0

Comment: sorry for my poor English.